# How do I install carpet tiles in a below grade room?

Tags: flooring, basement, tile, carpet, basement-refinishing

A few years ago, I saw an advertisement for carpet tiles that had a jagged edge so there would be less movement in the interlock between tiles, and prevented the need for glue. (would like to find these or similar)

I have a below grade room that has ceramic tile over concrete floor. We want to carpet this area, and figured carpet tiles might be the best/easiest way to accomplish this. Additionally, the room is a pass through from the garage to the main level and is a high traffic area.  We thought carpet tiles would be nice, as we could replace sections of it if need be.

That being said, we would like carpet tiles that don't have to be glued down. Any suggestions?

Also, should I put down a barrier (like you would with a floating floor)? Or put down a moisture block?

Additionally, do I need to make any considerations for the grout spacing in the tile (for the ceramic tile underneath)?

Update:

considering DriCore, but because of the chip board and lack of mold treatment, it has possible moisture issues.

Possible alternative: http://www.supersealonline.us/

and another alternative: http://www.spycor.com/DMX_Subfloor_for_Concrete_p/dmx1.htm

Comment: Is the current floor down there just concrete?

Comment: You don't need grout with carpet tiles.

Comment: @ChrisF - for the ceramic tiles underneath...

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo - 6" ceramic tile on concrete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to do this right and don't mind a little elbow grease.

## 1) Clean it up

Remove the ceramic tile, and strip the floor down to the bare concrete.  Technically you don't have to do this, but not doing it is, IMO, just lazy.  Building up the floor is convenient but not the best work you can do.

## 2) Build the base

Now that you're down to bare concrete, install [Dri-Core tiles](http://www.dricore.com/en/eIndex.aspx) or something similar for subflooring, making sure you add ventilation as per manufacturer instructions.  This product protects itself from moisture (except in a flood of course) and will likewise protect the tile from small moisture accumulations.

[image]

[image]

## 3) Put down whatever floor you like.

There are a number of interlocking carpet tile products available that allow you to do a floating style installation.

The grout question is a non issue if you remove the ceramic, as you should.

Comment: +1 for a very good solution. Have used DriCore and it is softer and warmer than a concrete base. However, it is a big job and it eats up about 3/4 inch, if ceiling height is an issue.

Comment: The thickness is a reason to remove the ceramic tile as well.

Comment: Ya, but you gain less than 1/4 and you lose slightly more than 3/4, if I recall right. Only an issue if a) it is low to begin and you care about how low or b) you have a building inspector with a a rigid view about 7 ft (or whatever code is) ceilings and this would tip it AND an inspection is necessary (need for new certificates of occupancy sometimes come up in resale).

Comment: Ceramic tile ranges in thickness from 1/4" to 3/4", and there's usually at least 1/4" of mortar underneath, so it's definitely gaining more than 1/4" by removing the old tile.

Comment: That is a good point. Depends on the tile and the thinset/bedding. I don't want to overplay the height thing, often not an issue at all.

Comment: Thanks. I have been looking at DriCore for a while, as I've seen them at Lowe's/Home Depot. Any other competing products?

Comment: interesting article about the shortcomings of DriCore: http://www.cqs.com/homeqa/dricore.htm

Comment: @Jason, broken link but found archived copy: https://web.archive.org/web/20150705165954/http://www.cqs.com/homeqa/dricore.htm